# Does the following serie converge?

Tags: real-analysis

Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{n+1}{4n+3})$ converge?

**attempt at solving the problem**

Using the ratio test we have $\frac{\mid\frac{n+2}{4n+7}\mid}{\mid\frac{n+1}{4n+3}\mid}$= $\frac{n+2}{4n+7}\frac{4n+3}{n+1}$= $\frac{4n^2+11n+6}{4n^2+11n+7}$

Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\mid\frac{n+1}{4n+3}\mid)$ converges. But all the values of the sum are positive, therefore,$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{n+1}{4n+3})$ converges

**End of the attempt**

Is that the right approach?

Comment: Why is that so?

Comment: You have asked 8 questions so far, but you haven't accepted any answer. If you continue like this, people will begin to avoid you and they will no longer answer your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term of your series tends to $\frac 1 4$, so your series diverges (if a series converges, then its term *must* tend to to $0$).

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n+1}{4n+3}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Hence, the necessary condition for convergence is not given.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ratio test, we get:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(n+1)+1}{4(n+1)+3}}{\frac{n+1}{4n+3}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{n+2}{4n+7}}{\frac{n+1}{4n+3}}\right|=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{n+2}{4n+7}\cdot\frac{4n+3}{n+1}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(n+2)(4n+3)}{(4n+7)(n+1)}\right|=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{4n+3}{4n+7}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{4+\frac{3}{n}}{4+\frac{7}{n}}\right|=\left|\frac{4}{4}\right|=1$$

And it is $1$, so we can't use the ratio test!

Answer (score 1):

$\lim n \rightarrow\infty\frac{n+1}{4n+3}=\frac{1}{4}\neq0$ 
Hence the series diverges.